# JWT based auth implementation, is it safe enough?

Tags: api, security, authentication, jwt

There are a lot of articles on the web describing why JWT is a broken solution to replace sessions, yet I have an implementation which mimics as sessions and is based on JWT and seems to be safe enough:

- Once user logs in a set of three tokens is returned: jwt access token with small expiration time, jwt refresh token with long expiration time, regular csrf token. In case of web apps access and refresh tokens are stored in http-only secure cookies, csrf is in the response body and should be handled by the client side: localStorage, in-memory - up to you. In case of 3rd-party clients (mobile, desktop, etc.) access and refresh tokens are also in the response body.
- Web and 3rd-party clients have different login endpoints: the one for web only requires username (or email) and password, the one for 3rd-party requires client-id and client-secret as well - treat this pair as app keys: they should be hard-coded in your client and stored in the back end's DB.
- Each refresh token can have only one valid access token associated to it. Access token's payload contains token's uid - uuid4 should be fine.
- When tokens are generated two entries should be added into the key-value store (redis, memcached, etc.), with appropriate key expiration timeout if supported by the store

  - [refresh-token-id] => [csrf-token, access-token's uid, access-token's expiration time]
  - [access-token-uid] => [csrf-token]
- API requests which do not require csrf token check (GET/HEAD or requests from 3rd-party clients) should only check access token itself and make no key-value store requests (or may do 'has-key' request if you want to have centralized password reset functionality). In case of csrf vulnerable requests single key-value store requests is done -> to check if requests's X-CSRF-Token header contains correct csrf token
- Refresh token request validates refresh token first, then makes key-value store request and checks if csrf token from X-CSRF-Token header is valid and if expiration time of the access token is appropriate -> this is a restriction for client implementations - refresh requests should be sent only when token gets expired, if refresh request is sent before access token's expiration time a notification should be sent to dev team since in production it might mean that refresh token hijack was made.
- If refresh token verification is ok key-value store keys should be updated: access token's uid key should be deleted, new access token's uid key should be created, csrf token should be updated and returned in the response.

Pros of the approach:

1. Access verification logic might make only single db request - only if you need to resolve current user. Some useful information might be stored in the access token's payload -> you might prevent api access by making no db/key-value store calls at all just by having roles or other access-specific data in your token and validating it right there. In case of POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE requests only single key-value store request is made - to validate csrf token and only in case of web clients, as other clients are not csrf vulnerable.
2. Cookie hijack for refresh tokens is prevented -> as only single access token is allowed per refresh token one of its owners (valid user or hacker) will have to make refresh request before current access token's expiration timeout -> in this case dev team can be notified about suspicious activity for specific refresh token.
3. You have support for both web and non-web clients
4. It's possible to have centralized password reset: you only need to invalidate all refresh tokens for current user, that means refresh tokens should be stored in the db as well in order to be able to find all key-value store representations of the refresh tokens. If it's important to drop all sessions instantly after password reset an additional check for access token should be done -> to check if its key is still in key-value store.